# How Can I set Kubernetes Cronjob to run at a specific time

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

When I set the Cronjob Schedule as `*/1 * * * *`,it would work.

When I set any number which is in `0-59` to the `crontab minute`,such as `30 * * * *`,it would work as well.

However when I set the Cronjob Schedule as `30 11 * * *`,it even doesn`t create a job at 11:30.

All the config is followed:

```
 apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
 kind: CronJob
 metadata:
   name: hello
 spec:
   schedule: "33 11 * * *"
   jobTemplate:
     spec:
       template:
         spec:
           containers:
             - name: hello-cronjob
               image: busybox
               command: ["bash","-c","date;echo  Hello from the Kubernetes cluste"]
           restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because your cluster is running in a different timezone then the one used by you.

You can check what timezone will be set in a `POD` using:

`kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- date`.

As for your `yaml` it looks good, there is no need to change anything with the `spec.schedule` value.

A small hint that might be helpful to you which is checking the logs from `Jobs`.

When you create `CronJob` when it's scheduled it will spawn a `Job`, you can see them using `kubectl get jobs`.

```
$ kubectl get jobs
NAME               DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
hello-1552390680   1         1            7s
```

If you use the name of that job `hello-1552390680` and set it as a variable you can check the logs from that job.

```
$ pods=$(kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=hello-1552390680 --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})
```

You can later check logs:

```
$ kubectl logs $pods
Tue Mar 12 11:38:04 UTC 2019
Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this once and test result

```
0 30 11 1/1 * ? *
```

http://www.cronmaker.com/

You might face the **Timezone** issue based on the Nodes running in different region, so take care accordingly.

Can leverage the **K8s 1.27 Timezone** field in **cronjob**

— Stable

Starting with **version 1.24**, CronJob includes the option to select the , with 1.27 it’s moving to stable. Previously job is scheduled by a cron job based on the time zone that the -- is currently running.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: tz-test
spec:
  timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
  schedule: "0 21 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: tz-test
            image: busybox
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo hello world!
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```